# how to upgrade version of m2e

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2e

I am using Eclipse Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1) and m2e version 1.5.0.20140606-0033.  I want to make sure that I have the latest stable version of m2e because I might be experiencing problems importing maven projects using m2e.  I see from [this link](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/) that version 1.6 has not been released yet at the time of this posting today, and I also see that the date on my current version above is only 4 months ago.

How can I make sure that I always have the most current version of m2e?

Comment: BTW I have exactly the same version and even older Luna (4.4.0).

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Eclipse to automatically check for updates for all the installed plugins. From the following website: http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-37a.htm

> You can configure Eclipse update to search for updates to the installed features on a periodic basis automatically. You can configure how these updates are scheduled and performed from the ***Windows -> Preferences -> Install/Update -> Automatic Updates*** preference page.

There you can define your:

- scheduling options - i.e. not at all, at startup or at a specific time.
- download options - search for updates and notify when available or download and notify when ready to install

Note there will be no notification if no updates are found.